# How can I tell if two Minecraft mods are compatible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

If I want to use two mods together, e.g. [SinglePlayerCommands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-173-single-player-commands-v210-2/) and [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-173-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-july-1/) (which don't state compatibility with one another), how can I tell if they will work together (and not break Minecraft - forcing me to re-download a fresh copy)?

Comment: (These two mods *do* work together (For an **awesome** building environment!))

Comment: One thing that can help you determine if two mods will work together is to check if any of the .class files in the mods have the same name. If so, the mods aren't compatible without merging the files.

Comment: Why do you ask yourself a question and comment it after to tell that's working ??

Comment: @Warface I am asking the question in the general case, the specific case I gave was an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Minecraft Mods really work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28023/how-do-minecraft-mods-really-work)

Comment: @Tom, I don't think that this is a duplicate, because the questions are trying to get different things answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no hard-and-fast rule other than simply installing them both and seeing if it blows up.  However, there *are* some tricks for guessing ahead of time.

Firstly, mods which use the same API/framework/loader (e.g. [ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v173-risugamis-mods-recipe-book-updated/) or [Minecraft Forge](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/514000-api-minecraft-forge/)) are much more likely to be compatible with one another than non-framework mods.  This is because those APIs are created specifically to help prevent mods from conflicting with one another.  (However, it's still possible — even easy — to create conflicts.)

Mods which use patchers are also somewhat more likely to be compatible with other mods if installed last.  (Patchers work by replacing small bits of Minecraft's code rather than entire files.)  However, patchers are few and far between.

The *best* rule-of-thumb indicator of whether two mods will conflict is to compare the list of `.class` files they contain.  If there are no files which exist in both mods, chances are good that they'll work just fine together.  If there *are* one or more files which exist in both, however, there will very likely be a conflict.

Finally, you can check the mods' documentation to see if they have notes about compatibility.  Sometimes, there will be special instructions for getting two mods to work together which otherwise conflict or descriptions of what functionality the conflict will break.  (e.g. [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-173-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-july-1/) and [Convenient Inventory](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/504091-v173-convenient-inventory-19/); [ControlPack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/355537-173-new-version-31-controlpack-autosneakrunsmartfurnacelookbehindlots-more-v31/) and [OptiMine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-173-optifine-hd-g-fps-boost/))

Comment: Single-Player Commands + Aether dependecies do not work :( i really wanted to play Aether...